# Open beta testing of the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: discussion, android-app

As you may or may not be aware, we've done [continuous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app?rq=1) [testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215992/stack-exchange-android-app-in-beta?rq=1) of our [Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) since before the initial launch.

As of around five seconds ago, thanks to new Google Play tools, we are starting **open enrollment into the beta tier** of our Android app.

If you'd like to enroll or unenroll into the beta tier, please visit: https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.stackexchange.marvin

After enrolling on that page you'll be able to see a beta version of the app when using the Play Store on your Android device. You'll still get the newest production version if we don't have anything actively in beta, but you can differentiate between the two tiers by looking at the release notes.

Beta updates's release notes begin with "NOTE: This is a beta update".

---

This post will be updated whenever we add in new beta features.

Version 1.0.78:

- Fix for [Android app should not scroll back to top of page when rotation occurs while writing a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311624/472021)

Version 1.0.77:

- Overhaul of how answer drafts are stored. We now properly support saving drafts for answer *edits* in addition to saving drafts for new answers.

Version 1.0.76:

- Fixed login with Google on Android 6.0 devices.
- Fixed a crash when trying to load certain feed item types on Android 6.0 devices.

Version 1.0.74:

- Switched out compile target from API 22 (Android 5.1) to API 23 (Android 6.0) to work with the new Marshmallow APIs and permission model.
- Fixed a crash when trying to join private beta sites.
- Fixed a bug when opening the app from a push notification while the app was not running previously, which resulted in an empty inbox being displayed in the app.

Version 1.0.73:

- Brings in the [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs) API which gives much faster access to loading external links from the app. Note that this is only supported on Chrome 45 and above right now, so you'll need to be using the "Chrome Beta" app on your phone to see it.
- Fixes a crash when trying to load a question then leaving the view before it's fully finished loading.

Version 1.0.72:

- Attempts to fix a possible crash when entering the app from
- Implementation of the [App Indexing API](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/) -- This means that you'll be able to quickly revisit questions and answers you've browsed in the app by searching from them using Google Now on your device.

If you have any feedback from beta testing, feel free to e-mail the team directly at androidapp@stackoverflow.com or post a comment or answer on this post.

Comment: You left some suspense in your question: *Attempts to fix a possible crash when entering the app from* .... will we ever know when the app crashes? ;)

Comment: @rene I couldn't repro the bug so I kind of just threw random possible fixes at it... :)

Comment: "*couldn't repro the bug so I kind of just threw random possible fixes at it*" 0_o What's "it"? As it's no-repro, did you throw random fixes at *random things*?

Comment: @James it's a state invalidation error that happens when trying to load a page after the app has been paused -- It seems to occur when the app is in a paused state in the background and a user re-enters via a push notification, so I put in some "if the app is paused please don't try to enter this state" logic to see if it fixes it.

Comment: Any plan to update the changelog of v1.0.74? Or should we move the changelog as a community-wiki answer? :)

Comment: @AndrewT. yeah uh I should probably do that