# Favoriting in the Android app

Tags: support, bug, android-app

Since yesterday I cannot favorite any question from the Android app any more. I always get

[image: Screenshot]

As has been shown (nicael's comment), this issue may be one with my own system - any ideas about how to find the cause?

Favoriting in the Web UI works as always.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dg9rT.png, i.e. norepro.

Comment: And can you favorite it using the site?

Comment: @nicael, yes, works as usual.

Comment: Now that you favorited the question, can you go to the app and unfavorite it?

Comment: Also, try voting up from the app.

Comment: Upvoting was no problem (the 8th was from me :-)), I could unfavorite it now, and could favorite it again.

Comment: Now try to fav any other question.

Comment: Now favoriting overall seems to work again - seems to have been a minor glitch in the app.

Comment: Are you using the beta channel? It was updated yesterday, possibly with some new bugs. @nicael what about you?

Comment: Okay then, great.

Comment: @Sha beta what channel?

Comment: The idea of trying to favorite in the web UI **should** have come to my mind before :-), now I suggest to close this question as "norepro" - I'd rather not delete it, because *somebody* might benefit.

Comment: @nicael both SE apps got something known as "beta" version which is updated much more often, and used to test for bugs. If you don't know what I mean it's fine, and means you're using the stable release. (i.e. downloaded from Google Play)

Comment: @Sha yeah me is stable.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, no beta here, didn't even know such a thing existed - is that an open beta?

Comment: @guntbert no, only those invited back when the app started can use it. (as far as I know)

Comment: [Open beta testing participation for Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262151/241919)

Comment: Also, this seems more like API call vs network race condition. I can reproduce the issue, though with difficulty. The real problem is, there's slight lag between pressing 'favorite' button and getting the message and updating the display (due to waiting for response from API). If you press the buttons consecutively, this issue may happen with "Question is already favorited" or "Question is not favorited"

Comment: (cnt'd) however, I don't see it as big issue other than confusion, since you actually can favorite the question.

Comment: @AndrewT. what you are describing is something different though.