# Can't open questions in the browser from the Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

Since the most recent update (I think), I can no longer open questions in the browser, which is one of the "more" options. This option is useful when you need to do something not supported by the mobile app, like viewing the revision history, but can be done in the mobile website.

Attempting to use this option will crash the app every time, without fail. This is definitely a regression, as in past versions (1.0.71) I have been able to use this option.

App version: 1.0.77
OS version: 6.0.1

Comment: Not repro'd on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app 1.0.78 (beta). I can open it on Chrome, though it doesn't open in [Chrome Custom Tabs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262151/241919) anymore.

Comment: Not repro'd on Android 4.4.4, app 1.0.77, so it might be specific for 6.0.1.

Comment: Previously I said "not repro'd", but I've somewhat repro'd this, is this the same issue with [“Open in browser” crashes when Android app is set as default](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273486/)?

Comment: @AndrewT. That does appear to be the same issue.

Comment: In the meantime, if you reset the app preference (**Settings - Apps - Stack Exchange - Open by default**, set *Open supported links* to *Ask every time* and **Clear Defaults**), can you use the *Open in Browser* again?