# Edit your answer draft failure in Android

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, draft

If you click on 'Edit your answer draft' at the button in the app:

[image: Edit answer]

you get an error message that says you are not connected to the Internet

[image: Not connected error]

If you click on the normal answer button it works like it should for the answer draft.

I'm using Android 5.0 on a Samsung Galaxy S5 if this is necessary.

Comment: Also happens on 6.0.1/Nexus 5.

Comment: Repro'd on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app v1.0.78 beta

Comment: I get this a lot on my Note 4, running 4.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about this, I broke it when doing the latest round of changes to drafts (to allow drafts on answer edits, not just new answers). It's fixed in any version greater than 1.0.80, currently only on [the beta tier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262151/open-beta-testing-of-the-stack-exchange-android-app).