# Some bugs while pulling to refresh

Tags: bug, android-app

Sometimes, when I push to refresh the question, something like this appears:

> [image: Clixk for larger version]

The bug I see is the rotating icon, it isn't showing correctly.

This is a bug I found recently when exploring questions through Stack Exchange.

Also, the top bar sometimes, when the page has been refreshed, appears like a white box (I couldn't take a snapshot of this). The white box draws over the question title.

My device info:
Os: Android KitKat (Miui 7 modification)
Device: Xiaomi Mi3

Comment: Could you mention your device model, Android version, and SE app version? Also, I think you need to clarify more about the issue, as I'm not sure based only on the screenshot: did you mean the rotating icon for pull-to-refresh get stuck after the post has been successfully refreshed? Also, by "*appears like a white box*", did you mean the title and tags weren't shown?

Comment: @AndrewT. The version of SE app is the latest.

Comment: Ah, I see, so it should be v1.0.77 then. I just want to make sure, since sometimes users are reporting bugs on older versions, and on the other hand, there's also [SE app beta participation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262151/open-beta-testing-of-the-stack-exchange-android-app). Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewT.  You're welcome!